# jquery to match <p> values based on a given value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a grid of staff in divs on a page and within each div i have added a new 'filter-content' div which contains the ids of various criteria that apply to this member of staff. Such as 'specialisms', 'region', 'joblevel' etc.

Here is my mark up:

```
foreach (SearchFirmRecruiter searchFirmRecruiter in Model.OrderBy(o => o.LastName))
        {
            bool blnUserDeactivated = searchFirmRecruiter.DateRemoved.HasValue;
            string strCipher = @searchFirmRecruiter.getSearchFirmRecruiterCipherId();

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default text-center @(blnUserDeactivated ? "deactivated" : "")">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o fa-3x"></i>
                        <p class="h4"><b>@searchFirmRecruiter.FirstName @searchFirmRecruiter.LastName</b></p>
                        <div class="filter-content">
                            <p class="specialisms"><b>@searchFirmRecruiter.Specialism</b></p>
                            <p class="regions"><b>@searchFirmRecruiter.Regions</b></p>
                            <p class="supplierType"><b>@searchFirmRecruiter.SupplierType</b></p>
                            <p class="jobLevel"><b>@searchFirmRecruiter.JobLevel</b></p>
                        </div>
                        <p><a href="mailto:@searchFirmRecruiter.Email">@searchFirmRecruiter.Email</a></p>
                        @if (blnUserDeactivated)
                        {
                            //Set the value
                            blnShowDisabledRecruitersLink = true;

                            <a data-href="@Url.Content("~")SearchFirm/ActivateRecruiter/@searchFirmRecruiter.getSearchFirmRecruiterCipherId()" data-toggle="confirmation" data-btn-ok-icon="fa fa-check" data-btn-cancel-icon="fa fa-remove" data-container="body" data-placement="top" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-check margin-right-spacing"></i>Enable</a>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <a href="~/SearchFirm/ManageRecruiter/@strCipher" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil margin-right-spacing"></i>Edit</a>
                            <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-container="body" data-trigger="hover" title="" data-original-title="This user will no longer be able to access their jobs and submit any candidates"><a data-href="@Url.Content("~")SearchFirm/DeactivateRecruiter/@strCipher" data-toggle="confirmation" data-btn-ok-icon="fa fa-check" data-btn-cancel-icon="fa fa-remove" data-placement="top" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-remove margin-right-spacing"></i>Disable</a></span>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

On the page the filter-content div looks like this:

,19,17,25,

,6,9,12,16,19,

,1,

,1,2,4,

Down the left hand side of the page i have some filter options, one for each of the

classes above. So these will list all the 'specialisms', 'regions' etc as checkboxes. When a filter checkbox is selected i am running a javascript function to filter for that filter type. So, for example, if a user selects the 'Accountancy' specialism and that is id 25. I want to only show the members of staff that have that 'Accountancy' specialism.

As the filters are clicked so the members of staff will be shown if they meet the criteria.

I am completely new to JQuery but i'm pretty sure this is the best way to achieve what i want.
I have a javascript function for each filter which passes in the selected filter value, within this funtion, ideally, i want to firstly hide all the divs and then show only the ones that match the filter criteria. At the moment i am just playing around with trying to return the specialisms, once i have those i can do some logic to determine if the passed in specialismId is contained and therefore whether this member of staff should be shown or not

```
function filterSpecialism(specialismId) {            

        alert(specialismId);
        alert($(".filter-content").find('p').find('specialisms').val)
}
```

Here is an image of how the page currently looks, so within this example Accountancy is selected as the filter, this is specialism id 25 so only James Dibner and Harjinder Royston should be shown

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oJqu.png)

I hope that all make sense and i appreciate any answers or suggestions. Many thanks all

Comment: I think it makes more sense to have the specialism ids as classes of the div for easier targeting instead of ids in the body. Have a look at this issue that I stumbled upon yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058189/filtering-result-based-on-checkboxes-with-jquery-using-value-and-class/45058414

Comment: Just a suggestion: try to use OData. It have build-in filtering system. Is is asp.net? They you just make call to odata controller with filter data and get only needed results.