# Get data- values from unspecified amount of child divs, but only after selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a previous question about filtering multiple items based on checkbox ticks (see here: [Filtering result based on checkboxes with jQuery using value and class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45058189/filtering-result-based-on-checkboxes-with-jquery-using-value-and-class)). The answer worked great, and did what it needed to do.

Further to this question, I'd now like to know how to get the data-apt-name values for the various items that are shown when a filter is applied. If you look at the JSFiddle below, you'll see you can filter by checking the boxes. You can filter within the results by checking more boxes in the various categories.

Basically, I need to get attributes from ONLY the returned results of the filter. With these attributes, I intend to toggle other divs in a later stadium, so that I can highlight/indicate which apartments meet the selected criteria.

Here's the catch (I think); the items in the 'apt results' div are not fixed in number as that list will be populated from a database eventually. The only thing I'll be certain of is the various class names per entry div for a home. So I could end up with 20 or 50 homes, and as a result with an X amount of results after filtering.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rh7p6Lh6/), and below is the (abridged) code:

```
<style>
body {width: 100%;}
#wrapper {width: 640px;overflow: auto;}
ul li {list-style-type: none;}
#aptresults {width: 300px;float: left;}
#selections {width: 330px;float: left;}
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">

        <div id="heading">
            <h1 class="inline">Homes</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="selections">
            <b>Oppervlakte</b>
            <ul class="apt-opper">
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="o50" id="o50" />
                    <label for="o50">50m2 - 100m2</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="o100" id="o100" />
                    <label for="o100">100m2 - 150m2</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="o150" id="o150" />
                    <label for="o150">150m2 - 200m2</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="o200" id="o200" />
                    <label for="o200">200m2 +</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <b>Type</b>
            <ul class="apt-type">
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="tPe" id="tPe" />
                    <label for="tPe">Penthouse</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="tV" id="tV" />
                    <label for="tV">Villa</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="tPa" id="tPa" />
                    <label for="tPa">Panorama</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="tU" id="tU" />
                    <label for="tU">Urban</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="tZ" id="tZ" />
                    <label for="tZ">Zuid</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <b>Prijs</b>
            <ul class="apt-price">
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="p1" id="p1" />
                    <label for="p1">1.000.000 - 2.000.000</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="p2" id="p2" />
                    <label for="p2">2.000.000 - 3.000.000</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="p3" id="p3" />
                    <label for="p3">3.000.000 - 4.000.000</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="p4" id="p4" />
                    <label for="p4">4.000.000 - 5.000.000</label>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <b>Balkon</b>
            <ul class="apt-balkon">
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="b50" id="b50" />
                    <label for="b50">50m2 - 100m2</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="b100" id="b100" />
                    <label for="b100">100m2 - 150m2</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="b150" id="b150" />
                    <label for="b150">150m2 - 200m2</label>
                </li>
                <li >
                    <input type="checkbox" value="b200" id="b200" />
                    <label for="b200">200m2 +</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

<!-- Random test list of items, will be populated from a database -->
        <div id="aptresults">
            <div class="apt o50 tU p1 b50" data-apt-name="apt_1_9">50m2 - Urban - 1mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o50 tPe p1 b50" data-apt-name="apt_1_10_">50m2 - Penthouse - 1mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o50 tZ p3 b150" data-apt-name="apt_2_1">50m2 - Zuid - 3mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o50 tPe p2 b50" data-apt-name="apt_3_2">50m2 - Penthouse - 2mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o50 tU p1 b50" data-apt-name="apt_4_1">50m2 - Urban - 1mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o50 tPe p2 b50" data-apt-name="apt_4_3">50m2 - Penthouse - 2mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o100 tZ p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_5_2">100m2 - Zuid - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_6_23">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_7_15">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_7_28">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_8_67">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o100 tZ p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_8_78">100m2 - Zuid - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o150 tV p3 b150" data-apt-name="apt_9_17">150m2 - Villa - 3mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o150 tV p3 b100" data-apt-name="apt_9_35">150m2 - Villa - 3mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o150 tV p3 b150" data-apt-name="apt_10_42">150m2 - Villa - 3mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o150 tV p2 b150" data-apt-name="apt_11_01">150m2 - Villa - 2mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o200 tPa p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_12_02">200m2 - Panorama - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o200 tZ p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_12_04">200m2 - Zuid - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o200 tPa p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_13_36">200m2 - Panorama - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
            <div class="apt o200 tZ p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_14_28">200m2 - Zuid - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
//  $('#aptresults div').show();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        select()
    })
});

function select()
{
    $('#aptresults div').hide();
    var $div=$('#aptresults div');
    var filter = [];
    var aptName = [];
    var check=false;

    $('ul').each(function()
    {
        filter = [];
        aptName = [];
        check = false;
        $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()
        {
            var css=$(this).val();          
            filter.push('.'+css);
            check = true;

            if(check == true) {
                $("#aptresults").children("div").each(function() {
                    aptName.push($(this).data("apt-name"));
                });
                aptName.push(""+aptName.join(","));
            }
        });

        if (check)
            {
                $div = $div.filter(filter.join(','));
            }
            console.log(aptName);
    })
    $div.show();
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rh7p6Lh6/, you can get div's filtered with :visible property of jquery  console.log($('.apt:visible'), 'element')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? `apt-name` values get displayed in console.

I loop through the results before you show the div and push the values in an Array called `results`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
  select()
 })
});

function select()
{
    $('#aptresults div').hide();
 var $div=$('#aptresults div');
 var filter = [];
 var aptName = [];
 var check=false;

 $('ul').each(function()
 {
  filter = [];
  aptName = [];
  check = false;
  $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()
  {
            var css=$(this).val();          
            filter.push('.'+css);
            check = true;

   if(check == true) {
    $("#aptresults").children("div").each(function() {
     aptName.push($(this).data("apt-name"));
    });
    aptName.push(""+aptName.join(","));
   }
     });
      
  if (check)
   {
    $div = $div.filter(filter.join(','));
   }
   //console.log(aptName);
    })
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < $div.length; i++){
     results.push($div[i].dataset.aptName);
    }
    console.log(results);
    $div.show();
}
```

```css
body {width: 100%;}
#wrapper {width: 640px;overflow: auto;}
ul li {list-style-type: none;}
#aptresults {width: 300px;float: left;}
#selections {width: 330px;float: left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">

        <div id="heading">
            <h1 class="inline">Homes</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="selections">
   <b>Oppervlakte</b>
   <ul class="apt-opper">
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="o50" id="o50" />
     <label for="o50">50m2 - 100m2</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="o100" id="o100" />
     <label for="o100">100m2 - 150m2</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="o150" id="o150" />
     <label for="o150">150m2 - 200m2</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="o200" id="o200" />
     <label for="o200">200m2 +</label>
    </li>
   </ul>
   
   <b>Type</b>
   <ul class="apt-type">
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="tPe" id="tPe" />
     <label for="tPe">Penthouse</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="tV" id="tV" />
     <label for="tV">Villa</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="tPa" id="tPa" />
     <label for="tPa">Panorama</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="tU" id="tU" />
     <label for="tU">Urban</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="tZ" id="tZ" />
     <label for="tZ">Zuid</label>
    </li>
   </ul>
   
   <b>Prijs</b>
   <ul class="apt-price">
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="p1" id="p1" />
     <label for="p1">1.000.000 - 2.000.000</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="p2" id="p2" />
     <label for="p2">2.000.000 - 3.000.000</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="p3" id="p3" />
     <label for="p3">3.000.000 - 4.000.000</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="p4" id="p4" />
     <label for="p4">4.000.000 - 5.000.000</label>
    </li>
   </ul>
   
   <b>Balkon</b>
   <ul class="apt-balkon">
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="b50" id="b50" />
     <label for="b50">50m2 - 100m2</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="b100" id="b100" />
     <label for="b100">100m2 - 150m2</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="b150" id="b150" />
     <label for="b150">150m2 - 200m2</label>
    </li>
    <li >
     <input type="checkbox" value="b200" id="b200" />
     <label for="b200">200m2 +</label>
    </li>
   </ul>
        </div>

<!-- Random test list of items, will be populated from a database -->
        <div id="aptresults">
   <div class="apt o50 tU p1 b50" data-apt-name="apt_1_9">50m2 - Urban - 1mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o50 tPe p1 b50" data-apt-name="apt_1_10_">50m2 - Penthouse - 1mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o50 tZ p3 b150" data-apt-name="apt_2_1">50m2 - Zuid - 3mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o50 tPe p2 b50" data-apt-name="apt_3_2">50m2 - Penthouse - 2mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o50 tU p1 b50" data-apt-name="apt_4_1">50m2 - Urban - 1mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o50 tPe p2 b50" data-apt-name="apt_4_3">50m2 - Penthouse - 2mil - 50m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o100 tZ p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_5_2">100m2 - Zuid - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_6_23">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_7_15">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_7_28">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o100 tU p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_8_67">100m2 - Urban - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o100 tZ p2 b100" data-apt-name="apt_8_78">100m2 - Zuid - 2mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o150 tV p3 b150" data-apt-name="apt_9_17">150m2 - Villa - 3mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o150 tV p3 b100" data-apt-name="apt_9_35">150m2 - Villa - 3mil - 100m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o150 tV p3 b150" data-apt-name="apt_10_42">150m2 - Villa - 3mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o150 tV p2 b150" data-apt-name="apt_11_01">150m2 - Villa - 2mil - 150m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o200 tPa p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_12_02">200m2 - Panorama - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o200 tZ p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_12_04">200m2 - Zuid - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o200 tPa p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_13_36">200m2 - Panorama - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
   <div class="apt o200 tZ p4 b200" data-apt-name="apt_14_28">200m2 - Zuid - 4mil - 200m2 balkon</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace this function:

```
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()
    {
        ...........
    }
```

by below mentioned function like this:

```
function select(){
    $('aptresults > div:visible').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('data-apt-name'));
        var aptName = [];
        aptName[] = $(this).attr('data-apt-name');
    });
    console.log(aptName);
}
```